# Fetch Opportunity whose date field is less than 7days from today

Tags: soql

the senario is their is date field in opportunity and i want fetch tht opportunity whose date field is less than 7 days from today.

means like today is 18/05/2018. i want fetch tht opp whose date is 11/05/2018.

I tried but Illegal assigment error occured.

```
[Select Id, StageName, Status__c, Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c, First_Payment_Due_Date__c From Opportunity 
where (Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c !=Null) 
AND (Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c =Today-7) 
AND  (First_Payment_Due_Date__c !=Null) 
AND (First_Payment_Due_Date__c = Today- 30) ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Date variables which will return your desired dates as follows (negative will count backwards):

```
Date dt = System.Today().addDays(-7);

Date PaymentDueDt = System.Today().addDays(-30);
```

SOQL will be as follows upon passing `dt` and `PaymentDueDt`

```
[Select Id, StageName, Status__c, Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c, First_Payment_Due_Date__c From Opportunity 
where (Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c !=Null) 
AND (Last_Payment_Date_Thru_Today__c =:dt) 
AND  (First_Payment_Due_Date__c !=Null) 
AND (First_Payment_Due_Date__c =:PaymentDueDt) ];
```

Comment: thnk u its working.

Answer (score 1):

Other Than Santanu's way, you can leverage [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) feature as well. These Date literals comes really handy when you just need to retrieve data from specific time duration.

**See this SOQL**:

> SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365